# Building for UIKit for Mac, but the linked framework 'XXX.framework' was built for macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xcode11, macos-catalina

I have created a new app which runs on both iPhone & Mac on Xcode 11 Beta 2 via Project Catalyst. For that I have 2 frameworks which are specifically build for 'macOS' & 'iOS'. Once I am adding that framework, I am receiving following error!

[image]

Here how I have added frameworks to the project!

[image]

Can anybody please help? Although, without adding frameworks project is running which just only have 2 `UILabel`.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem and found a possible solution in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117346

Answer (score 0):

This "macOS" platform in the project settings might be confusing, because it actually means macOS Catalyst only.

The error message means that the framework was built for the usual macOS platform, not for macOS Catalyst.

AFAIK you can't mix macOS libraries and frameworks into the Catalyst apps
( Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117229 ) right now (Xcode 11.6, August, 2020).

In order to fix this, you need to somehow obtain a version of the framework that is rebuilt from source specifically for Catalyst.

When building for Catalyst there are a few build configuration differences in the way the library is made, and some notable ones are:

- SDK_NAME=macosx10.15
- clang -target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi

... and probably more.